# From where did preorder, postorder and inorder traversal of a tree got its name?

Tags: data-structures

Just curious. I seem to forget them everytime.

Comment: From the Latin derived prefixes *pre-* and *post-*, meaning *before* and *after*, and the preposition *in*, meaning *between*...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Pre-* means "before"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pre-) and [*post-* means "after"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post-). In *preorder* traversal, you process a node *before* processing its children. In *postorder* traversal, you process a node *after* processing its children. In *inorder* traversal, you process a node *in between* processing its children.

Comment: Could **in**order perhaps be from 'intra'? It's a prefix (added to adjectives), meaning on the inside; within. https://www.google.com/search?q=Dictionary#dobs=intra