# In- pre- and post-order NAMES

Tags: inorder, preorder, postorder

What is the logic behind the names in-order, pre-order and post-order? Why are they called like that?

- In-order. Why the word "in", what is it "in"?
- Pre-order. "Pre", means "previous", but previous what?
- Post-order. "Post" means "after", but after what?

I know that there are previous threads asking how one traverses a tree using these orders and such. NOTE THAT THAT IS NOT WHAT I'M ASKING HERE SO IT'S NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION. I'm asking what is the meaning of the names. Why are they called like they are called.

Comment: Hate to reference wikipedia, but go here for a reasonable explanation -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From where did preorder, postorder and inorder traversal of a tree got its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545167/from-where-did-preorder-postorder-and-inorder-traversal-of-a-tree-got-its-name)

Answer (score 10):

To my understanding, the terminology refers to the position where the root node of the argument is processed. Let `r` be the root of a binary tree with left subtree `A` and right subtree `B`. For inorder, the sequence of processing is `ArB`, for preorder it is `rAB` and for postorder it is `ABr`.